# Passing a form and list box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to develop a sub that I can pass different variables to save me some time when creating quite a few different types of listbox in VBA Access.  I've come up with the following:

```
Public Sub openCASEFORM(f As Form, list As ListBox)
DoCmd.OpenForm f, , , "[FileID]=" & f.list
End Sub
```

And I call it as follows:

```
Private Sub listPreAn_Click()
Call openCASEFORM(Me, listPreAn)
End Sub
```

However when trying it I get a Run-time error '2465' Application-defined or object-defined error.  I'm struggling to see where it's going wrong.  Any thoughts?

Comment: where do your `Form` object come from in your first sub ?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use
Call openCaseFORM(Me, Me!listPreAn
?

Well of if you do not use list as Listbox as second parameter, You are not using it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really badly written, as you're passing objects but you need to use strings to do the job. I'd rewrite it thus:

```
  Public Sub openCASEFORM(f As String, list As String)
    DoCmd.OpenForm f, , , "[FileID]=" & f(list)
  End Sub
```

Either that, or:

```
  Public Sub openCASEFORM(f As String, list As ListBOx)
    DoCmd.OpenForm f, , , "[FileID]=" & list.Value
  End Sub
```

Both of these assume the listbox is a simple one (i.e., not multiselect).

I would suggest that it would make more sense to rewrite thus:

```
  Public Sub openCASEFORM(ByVal strFormName As String, ByVal strCriteria As String)
    DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName, , , strCriteria
  End Sub
```

That way, you could pass any arbitrary WHERE clause you liked.